# Spark BlockManager running on localhost

Tags: apache-spark

I have a simple script file I am trying to execute in the spark-shell that mimics the tutorial [here](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html)

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

sc.stop();

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp").setMaster("mesos://zk://172.24.51.171:2181/mesos").set("spark.executor.uri", "hdfs://172.24.51.171:8020/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4.tgz").set("spark.driver.host", "172.24.51.142")

val sc2 = new SparkContext(conf)

val file = sc2.textFile("hdfs://172.24.51.171:8020/input/pg4300.txt")

val errors = file.filter(line => line.contains("ERROR"))

errors.count()
```

My namenode and mesos master are on 172.24.51.171, my ip address is 172.24.51.142.  I have these line saved to a file, which I then launch using the command:

```
/opt/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-shell -i WordCount.scala
```

My remote executors are all dying with errors similar to the following:

```
15/04/08 14:30:39 ERROR RetryingBlockFetcher: Exception while beginning fetch of 1 outstanding blocks 
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:48554
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:191)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$1.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.start(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:120)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService.fetchBlocks(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.network.BlockTransferService.fetchBlockSync(BlockTransferService.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doGetRemote$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:594)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doGetRemote$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:592)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doGetRemote(BlockManager.scala:592)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemoteBytes(BlockManager.scala:586)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$$getRemote$1(TorrentBroadcast.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:136)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:119)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1152)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:48554
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:208)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:287)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    ... 1 more
```

This failure happens after I run the errors.count() command.  Earlier in my shell, after I create the new SparkContext I see the lines:

```
15/04/08 14:31:18 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 48554
15/04/08 14:31:18 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/04/08 14:31:18 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Registering block manager localhost:48554 with 265.4 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(<driver>, localhost, 48554)
15/04/08 14:31:18 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
```

I guess whats happening is Spark is recording the address of the BlockManager as localhost:48554, which is then getting sent to all the executors who try to talk to their localhosts:48554, instead of the driver's ip address at port 48554.  **Why is spark using localhost as the address of the BlockManager and not spark.driver.host?**

Additional Information

1. In the [Spark Config](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/configuration.html) there is a spark.blockManager.port but no spark.blockManager.host?  There is only a spark.driver.host, which you can see I set in my SparkConf.
2. Possibly related to this [JIRA Ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6420) although that seemed like a network issue.  My network is configured with DNS just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try by providing Spark Master address using --master parameter when invoking the spark-shell (or add in spark-defaults.conf). I had a similar issue (see my post [Spark Shell Listens on localhost instead of configured IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810054/spark-shell-listens-on-localhost-instead-of-configured-ip-address)) and it looks like BlockManager listens on localhost when the context is dynamically created in the shell.

Logs:

- When original context is used  (listens on hostname)
   BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on ubuntu64server2:33301
- When new context is created  (listens on localhost)
   BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on localhost:40235

I had to connect to a Cassandra cluster and was able to query it by providing spark.cassandra.connection.host in spark-defaults.conf and importing packages  com.datastax.spark.connector._ in the spark shell.

Comment: "BlockManager listens on localhost when the context is dynamically created in the shell"  this is my conclusion as well but seems lie counter-intuitive behavior.  Setting the spark.master in spark-defaults.conf fixed this for me

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` (on the command line) or `spark.local.ip` through the `sparkConf` object.

Comment: Hi maasg -- no effect, according to the configuration pages, spark.local.ip is not a part of the configuration in Spark 1.2.1 or Spark 1.3.0.  See my question for the link