# Spark BlockManager listening to localhost

Tags: apache-spark, networking, mesos

Not sure why and already looked into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523154/spark-blockmanager-running-on-localhost), with no luck.

My executors are listening to their localhost address, runining any kinf of shuffle operation as they can't talk to eacother.

I am running Spark on Mesos and already have the following variables pointing to their own IP (not localhost):

- SPARK_LOCAL_IP
- LIBPROCESS_IP

This is the process at the end, blacked out part is the "external ip"

[image]

This is the proess at the end

[image]
I am confused, how to trick the executor to expose his own IP but not to localhost.

Looks like it's not resolving correctly.

**EDIT** If I start the BlockManager manually using the ipv4 address 172.12.12.12 (example) the executor then binds to the correct address, but then if I use the dns address myserver.myservice.aws the executor binds to localhost.

Does anybody know why and how to solve it? Change the resolution issue or make mesos call the ipv4 address?

Comment: did you set SPARK_LOCAL_IP in spark_env.sh? I am not if that exist in mesos like standalone.

Comment: @Salim yes, SPARK_LOCAL_IP and MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY are present in spark-env.sh